# Find the smallest numbers in the second column corresponding to index values in first column

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have some very large tables and I need to extract specific rows. I am illustrating the task using a simple example. Say, I have weighed a number of apples, bananas and oranges. I need to extract the weight of the smallest apple, banana and orange

### Original table:

```
Apple 3
Banana 8
Orange 2
Apple 7
Banana 9
Orange 13
Apple 9
Banana 1
Orange 11
```

### Desired output:

```
Apple 3
Banana 1
Orange 2
```

Comment: If you where doing it just for apples, then how would you do it?

Comment: In answer to richard's question: I'd grep for Apple, then sort by second column, and output the first line using head -n1, but there must be more efficient ways of doing it that I don't know (yet)!

Comment: I would be grateful if you would apply the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)'s comment about no chit-chat in future posts yourself. Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '($2<a[$1] || !a[$1]){a[$1]=$2}END{for(f in a){print f,a[f]}}' file
Orange 2
Banana 1
Apple 3
```

`a[$1]=$2` sets up an array called `a`, whose keys are the 1st field and whose value is the second. The script above will save the second field as the value for the first in the array if i) it is smaller than the value stored or ii) there is no value stored. The `END` block iterates over the array printing its contents.

---

With GNU `sort`:

```
$ sort -nk2 file |  sort -u -k1,1
Apple 3
Banana 1
Orange 2
```

The first sort will print the lines in ascending order of weight (the 2nd field) and the second will only keep unique lines, but checks the 1st field only. The result is that the first occurrence of each string is printed which, because of the 1st sort, will be the smallest value for that fruit.

---

And a (slightly) shorter Perl:

```
$ perl -lane '$k{$F[0]}//=$F[1]; $k{$F[0]}=$F[1] if $F[1]<$k{$F[0]}; 
              END{print "$_ $k{$_}" for keys(%k)}' file 
Orange 2
Apple 3
Banana 1
```

The `//=` will assign a value unless the variable already has one. Then, the approach is the same as the `awk` one. We create the hash `%k` whose keys are the fruit and whose values their weight, and save the smallest value. The `-a` flag causes `perl` to act like `awk` and split its input on whitespace into the `@F` array.

Answer (score 3):

With `gnu` [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -s -g 1 min 2 <infile
```

```
Apple 3
Banana 1
Orange 2
```

This `s`orts and `g`roups by `1`st field printing the `min` value in `2`nd field for each ID in the 1st field. It assumes the fields are separated by single tab. Use `-W, --whitespace` if they're separated by multiple blanks or `-t, --field-separator=` to define another field separator e.g. single space:

```
datamash -t' ' -s -g 1 min 2 <infile
```

Since `datamash` requires sorted input, the output will be also sorted by the 1st field.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using perl oneliner:

```
perl -ane '$h{$F[0]} = $F[1] if (!defined $h{$F[0]} || $h{$F[0]} > $F[1]); 
           END {foreach (keys %h) {print "$_ $h{$_}\n"}}' fruits_list.txt
```

Here we are using a hash map (%h) to store elements. If the fruit is not yet present in the hash we add its first value, if it exists already, we update the value only if it is smaller that the value already stored. The END block is executed only after the last line of the file is processed, it prints the hash map.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -k2,2n file | sort -u -k1,1
```

Output:

```
Apple 3
Banana 1
Orange 2
```

Comment: With some `sort` implementations, you won't get a warranty that the second `sort` will preserve the numeric order. With some `sort` implementations, you can add the `-s` option to get that warranty.