# awk how I could print only the largest value per record?

Tags: awk

I have a input like this ; i need to filter the greater record value

```
cat;5
dog;3
bird;2
cat;3
dog;6
bird;8
```

for output a result like this

```
cat;5
dog;6
bird;8
```

Comment: [Find the smallest numbers in the second column corresponding to index values in first column](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233693) - you can easily adapt any of the answers there to print the _max_ instead of the _min_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ";";
}

{
  if($2 > a[$1]) { a[$1] = $2 }
  else { a[$1] = $2 }
}

END {
  for(x in a) { print x, a[x] }
}
```